# i have a list of number that come from function [1,2,3,4....] and i need to find min out of them in different function

Tags: python

so far i have

```
def minimum(y,l):
    for y in l:
        w=[l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3],l[4])
        a= min([l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3],l[4])

    return a


def menu(x,l): 
    if x == 1:
        make_table(l)
    if x == 2:
        y= int(input("enter a row (as a number) or a column (as an uppercase letter")
        if y in [ "1",'2','3']:
               minimum = minimum(y,l)
            print("Minmum is:",minimum(y,l))
    if x== 3:
        print ('bye')
```

i am a beginner in python and the function i pass through is not getting the data from the bottom function,

Comment: python has a min built-in

Comment: @Raiyan It looks like they are using it in the `minimum` function

Comment: In your `minimum` function, what does the `w` variable do?  You create it but never use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting an integer in y but then you are evaluating if it's in an array of strings therefore it is never going to get in there to call the minimum function

```
def minimum(y,var):
    for y in var:
        w=(var[0],var[1],var[2],var[3],var[4])
        a= min(var[0],var[1],var[2],var[3],var[4])

    return a



def menu(x,var): 
    if x == 1:
        make_table(var)
    if x == 2:
        y = raw_input("enter a row (as a number) or a column (as an uppercase letter)")
        if y in [ '1','2','3']:
            mini = minimum(y, var)
            print("Minimum is:", mini) # dont need this.
            print("Minimum is:", min(var)) # this should be all you really need.
    if x == 3:
        print ('bye')

menu(2,[1,2,3,4,5]) # calling the menu function
```

You had a bunch of issues with with matching your braces in your minimum function. also you cant have a variable with the same name as a function within the same scope `minimum = minimum(y,l)`. The minimum function doesnt make much sense the for loop is not doing anything really. anyways it works, good luck.

Comment: so do i need to change y to string if i want to compare them

Comment: the input() function returns a string so y is already a string

Comment: I would also recommend never to make a variable name the letter `l` to close to the number `1`

Comment: sure, i will keep that in mind and how can i call the function to get the min.thank you

Comment: It might be worth asking what `w` does in the `minimum` function.  In fact the entirety of the `minimum` function does not make sense.  You updated the syntax, but why not try and improve the logic?

Comment: Because you dont need that function at all. There is a built-in function `min()` that does what the minimum function does. In fact the OP uses it in his minimum function. I highlighted that in my answer `print("Minimum is:", min(var)) # this should be all you really need.`

Comment: I see that, but there are 2-3 things that the OP did that show a lack of knowledge of some of pythons features, or a misunderstanding of how to implement the logic of what they want.  Since this site tries to help people, it might be worth illustrating exactly what it is about the function that makes no sense/doesn't do what they intend.

Comment: In addition, the way you have updated the code, `min(var)` is being called each time in the loop, but it will give the same answer, so the looping is just wasting time and will print more stuff to the screen than needed.  Perhaps because the OP was looping and passing a variable to `minimum`, they actually wanted to do more than just `min` (you never asked what their intent was, and it's not clear at all from the code).  If not, it would be worth demonstrating the "right" way to call it (i.e. not in a loop).